# Importing packages in Python, attribute error

Tags: python, import, package, attributeerror

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to understand how packages and import statement work.
I made this package, located in my Desktop:

```
package/
   __ init __.py
   module2.py
   subpackage1/
      __ init __.py
      module1.py
```

Here's what's inside __ init __ .py in the package folder:

```
__ all __ =["module2"]
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/Leo--/Desktop/Package")
import subpackage1.module1
os.chdir("C:/Users/Leo--/Desktop")
```

and inside __ init __ .py in subpackage1 folder:

```
__ all __ =["module1"]
```

I want to import module1.py and module2.py by only writing

```
import package
```

After typing the command above into the interpreter I can access with no problems any function of module1.py by writing

```
package.subpackage1.module1.mod1()
```

where mod1() is a function defined in module1.py.
But when I type

```
package.module2.mod2()
```

I get "AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'module2'" (mod2() is a function defined in module2.py).
Why is that? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the `AttributeError` because you haven't imported the `module2` in `__init__.py` file.

You shouldn't do `os.chdir()` in `__init__.py` to import submodules.

This is how I would do it:

`__ init __.py` in the `package` directory.

```
from . import module2
from . import subpackage
```

`__ init __.py` in the `subpackage1` directory.

```
from . import module1
```

Comment: Thank you, but then what's the purpose of allowing the command "import some_package" if it basically does nothing? (assuming __ init __ .py blank)

Comment: @LeonardoMutti I didn't understand. What you mean?

Comment: Let's consider the package structure I mentioned above, and let's say that __ init __ .py is a blank file. If I type "import package", what's the effect of the command?

Comment: __ init __.py is to mark a directory as python package. With `import package` you won't be able to access `package.module2` or `package.subpackage1.module1` but `from package import module2` will work.